# How to Format a string on a textedit box in QErrorMessage in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How to make a new line on TextEdit Box in QErrorMessage ? and How to trim the blank space in  windows headings? Here is My Code,

```
    self.error_msg = QErrorMessage()
    self.error_msg.setFixedSize(500,200)
    
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    filename = exc_traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename
    lineno = exc_traceback.tb_lineno
    name = exc_traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_name
    type = exc_type.__name__
    message = exc_value
    nl = '\n'

    self.error_msg.setWindowTitle(f'{type}')
    self.error_msg.showMessage(f'File Name : {filename[:-3]}{nl}Line No. : {lineno}')
    print(f'File Name : {filename[:-2]}{nl} Line No. : {lineno}')
```

**This code produces the following result:**

[image]

How to trim the blank space in windows headings ( Space between AttributeError and question mark) and How to make a new line in Qtextedit box ( **File name** is in first line, **Line No** in next line)

Comment: What do you mean by "blank space in windows headings"?

Comment: @musicamante , in my pict, there is some gap between attributeError and question mark, that question mark is not in my code. My expetation is "AttributeError ?                "

Comment: That question mark is not part of the title. *ALL* dialogs in Windows have it, it's the context help button of the title bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text field is a standard QTextEdit, and `showMessage()` actually uses [`setHtml()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#html-prop).

In HTML, new line characters are treated as white spaces (and merged with them in the same manner). Just use the standard HTML line break separator:

```py
n1 = '<br/>'
```

That question mark has nothing to do with the *title text*, nor QErrorMessage: it's the standard context help button that exists on **any** standard Windows dialog (so, all QDialog subclasses use it by default). Since it's a window flag, just use the standard method for customizing window hints:

```py
self.error_msg.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint, False))
```